# Setting up an incoming CNAME to accept for my domain name

Tags: domains, redirects, dns

I have the following scenario.

Domain Name : **mydomain.com**

I have registered a country level tdl with our ISP.
country tdl : **www.mydomain.com.qa**

ISP has created a CNAME to my **www.mydomain.com.qa** to point to **mydomain.com**.

The problem is, when I enter **www.mydomain.com.qa** on browser's address bar, it shows my default page of the webserver instead of showing **mydomain.com**.

Can anybody suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to configure www.domain.com.qa to point to the place where the domain.com files are. Are you on shared hosting? If so, which company?

Comment: Your web server needs to be configured to handle the new domain.  What web server are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have a Dedicated server with Plesk Panel running on RHEL 5. How I would configure? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

After CNAME in DNS, you **have** to assign in Hosting Panel (can say nothing about Plesk) 
www-site as alias for mydomain.com (which also must to exist)